# Symfony2 assetic:dump FileNotFoundException

Tags: symfony, yui, assetic

So, there is a problem: i try to build assetic dumps with symfony2 on Windows machine through:

```
    php app/console assetic:dump
```

And then i get the following:

```
    [dir+] D:/Projects/domain/app/../web/js/compiled
    [file+] D:/Projects/domain/app/../web/js/compiled/main.js

    [Assetic\Exception\FilterException]
    An error occurred while running:
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" "-jar" "D:/Projects/domain/app/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar" "--charset" "UTF-8" "-o" "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\YUIF039.tmp" "--type" "js" "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\YUIF038.tmp"

    Error Output:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: UsersusernameAppDataLocalTempYUIF039.tmp:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\YUIF038.tmp (the filename,directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

    Input:
    var a = 1;
    alert (a);
```

Folder "web/js/compiled" is created but stays empty.
I can see "in real time" how YUIF03*.tmp files were created and removed during this operation in my TEMP folder.
This problem takes place on both Windows machines i've tried, but I have no problems with this on Linux virtual machine.
It seems like there is a problem with incorrect file path

```
    UsersusernameAppDataLocalTempYUIF039.tmp:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\YUIF038.tmp
```

but i have no idea about the source of the problem (Java? YUICompressor? Symfony2? Assetic?)

Here are some configurations of my symfony2.
composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
},
```

config.yml:

```
    # Assetic Configuration
    assetic:
        debug:          %kernel.debug%
        use_controller: false
        bundles:        [ AcmeWebBundle ]
        java: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
        filters:
            cssrewrite: ~
            yui_js:
                jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same, it is a yui 2.4.8 error : https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/78

Just use 2.4.7 : https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/downloads (the .jar is on the "build" folder).

```
java: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/java.exe"
filters:
    yui_css:
        # 2.4.8 fail on windows
        jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Not sure where it comes from, however, the symfony documentation indicates that ["The YUI Compressor is going through a deprecation process."](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html) so it is probably not supported anymore.

I managed to get it to work by trying different JRE and yuicompressor.jar versions. Here is the assetic config that worked for me (Win7 64bits):

```
# Assetic config
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ MyBundle ]
    java: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
        yui_js:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```

Note the specific jre6 path (by default the jre installed on my machine was jre7 with which I get the error) and the 2.4.7 yuicompressor version (does not work with 2.4.8).